# Prove that $R_1+R_2+R_3=R+r$,where $R$ is the circumradius and $r$ is the inradius of $\triangle ABC.$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider a triangle $DEF$,the pedal triangle of the triangle $ABC$ such that $A-F-B$ and $B-D-C$ are collinear.If $H$ is the incenter of $\triangle DEF$ and $R_1,R_2,R_3$ are the circumradii of the quadrilaterals $AFHE;BDHF;$ and $CEHD$ respectively,then prove that $R_1+R_2+R_3=R+r$,where $R$ is the circumradius and $r$ is the inradius of $\triangle ABC.$

---

As $DEF$ is a pedal triangle and $H$ is its incenter,so $HF$ is perpendicular to $AB,HD$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and $HE$ is perpendicular to $AC$.Therefore $AFHE,BFHD,CDHE$ are cyclic quadrilaterals.
I am stuck here.I have no idea how to solve further.

Comment: Can you look at this 'Geogebra' sketch?  http://ggbtu.be/mYGzCnuPZ I have a problem replicating the circumcircles of the quadrilaterals in your question. Thanks ...

Comment: For those that care to look at the sketch mentioned, the point H is the inCentre of DEF but point K is the 'pedal point'. Each segment KE, KF, KD is perpendicular to the sides of ABC. While circumCircles can be formed to involve point K there are no circumCircles involving point H as described in the question. I have flagged the question for closer examination.

Comment: @user255098 Vinod: You did not address my concerns in my comments [21st April]. Can you do this in the next couple of days? Otherwise I will assume you have no objection that I quote your question verbatim to the website to see if anyone else can assist with this construction

Comment: @userr255098 Vinod: From your question ${R_3}$ is radius of circumcircle of CEHD. In my sketch no such circumcircle can be constructed. Can you explain? I have made a change. See http://ggbtu.be/mYGzCnuPZ Thank you. I would like to clear up this mystery.

Comment: Yes it cannot be constructed by geogebra, so does it mean that this question is wrongly framed?@Benedict

Comment: @userr255098 Yes, it must mean the question was put incorrectly. Any chance of double checking with the source of the problem? I would be interested to know - hope so! Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AF = b$cosA$ and AE = c$cosA$ which implies that $$EF = acosA$$
Similarly it can be found that DE = c$cosC$ , FD = b$cosB$
$$R_1+R_2+R_3=\frac{acos{A}}{sinA}+\frac{bcos{B}}{sinB}+\frac{ccos{C}}{sinC}$$  (From Sine rule in respectice triangles)
$$\frac{a}{\sin{A}}=\frac{b}{\sin{B}}=\frac{c}{\sin{C}}= R$$
(From Sine Rule in the bigger triangle)
$$R_1+R_2+R_3=R\cos{A}+R\cos{B}+R\cos{C}$$
Also, we know that 
$$\cos{A}+\cos{B}+\cos{C} = 1+\frac{r}{R}$$
Which implies,
$$R_1+R_2+R_3=R+r$$
I hope this was helpful.

Comment: I did not understand this answer.Why you took $R_1=\frac{a\cos A}{\sin A}+\frac{b\cos B}{\sin B}+\frac{c\cos C}{\sin C}$.@Varun Kumar

Comment: It's actually $R_1+R_2+R_3=\frac{acos{A}}{sinA}+\frac{bcos{B}}{sinB}+\frac{ccos{C}}{sinC}$. It can be explained as follows,
 as $R_1$ is the circumradius of triangle AEF, it is equal to $\frac{EF}{\sin{A}}$ where EF = acosA. And similarly $R_2$ and $R_3$ follow.

Comment: Can you please show me how $EF=a\cos A,DE=c\cos C,FD=b\cos B$@Varun Kumar

Comment: AF = $bcosA$ , AE = $ccosA$ and angle between AF and AE is A.By applying cosine rule using these three parameters we get EF = $acosA$

Comment: Pleased that I was helpful.